# Flutter SVG gradient is not rendered: Image is rendering white

Tags: flutter, dart, svg

I have this gradient image

but it seems that flutter_svg is not able to render it.

The code of the image is below

```
<svg width="43" height="43" viewBox="0 0 43 43" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M28.4 15.7L21.5 7.09998L14.6 15.7C14.6 15.7 8.80002 22 11 28C11 28 12.9 35.6 21.5 35.8C30 35.7 32 28 32 28C34.2 22 28.4 15.7 28.4 15.7Z" fill="url(#paint0_linear_46_5)"/>
<path d="M21.5 36C17 35.9 14.4 33.7 13 32C11.5 30.1 10.9 28.2 10.9 28.2C8.80002 22.2 14.5 15.9 14.5 15.8L21.4 7.19998L28.3 15.8C28.4 15.9 34.1 22.2 31.9 28.2C31.9 28.2 31.4 30.2 29.8 32.1C28.6 33.8 25.9 35.9 21.5 36ZM21.5 35.8C25.9 35.8 28.5 33.6 29.9 31.9C31.5 30 32 28.1 32 28C34.1 22 28.4 15.8 28.4 15.7L21.5 7.09998L14.6 15.7C14.6 15.8 8.90002 22.1 11 28C11 28 11.5 29.9 13 31.8C14.4 33.6 17.1 35.7 21.5 35.8Z" fill="#221F20"/>
<path d="M20.9 26.4C20.7 26.4 20.6 26.4 20.4 26.4C20.4 26.4 20.4 26.4 20.3 26.4C19.9 26.4 19.4 26.4 19 26.4C18.8 26.4 18.6 26.3 18.4 26.3C18.2 26.2 18.2 26 18.2 25.7C18.2 25.6 18.2 25.5 18.2 25.3C18.2 25.1 18.3 24.8 18.6 24.8C18.8 24.8 19.1 24.7 19.3 24.6C19.4 24.5 19.5 24.4 19.4 24.3C19.4 24.2 19.3 24.1 19.1 24.1C19 24.1 18.8 24.1 18.7 24.1C18.6 24.1 18.4 24 18.3 24C18.2 24 18.2 23.9 18.2 23.7C18.2 23.6 18.2 23.5 18.3 23.4C18.3 23.3 18.3 23.2 18.2 23.1C18 23 18 22.9 18 22.7L18.1 22.6C18.2 22.6 18.3 22.6 18.4 22.6C19 22.6 19.5 22.6 20.1 22.6C20.6 22.6 21.2 22.6 21.7 22.6C21.8 22.6 22 22.6 22.1 22.6C22.6 22.6 23.1 22.6 23.6 22.6C23.6 22.6 23.6 22.6 23.7 22.6C24 22.6 24.2 22.6 24.5 22.6C24.9 22.6 25.2 22.6 25.6 22.6C26.4 22.6 27.2 22.6 28 22.6C28.1 22.6 28.1 22.6 28.2 22.6C28.4 22.6 28.4 22.6 28.5 22.8C28.5 22.8 28.5 22.8 28.5 22.9C28.6 23.2 28.6 23.2 28.3 23.2C28.2 23.2 28.1 23.3 28.1 23.4C28.1 24.1 28.2 24.8 28.2 25.5C28.2 25.8 28.2 26 28.2 26.3C28.2 26.4 28.1 26.5 28 26.5C27.8 26.5 27.6 26.5 27.5 26.5C27.4 26.5 27.4 26.4 27.4 26.3C27.4 25.7 27.4 25.1 27.4 24.5C27.4 24.3 27.4 24 27.4 23.8C27.4 23.5 27.3 23.4 27 23.4C26.6 23.4 26.6 23.5 26.6 23.8C26.6 24.1 26.6 24.5 26.6 24.8C26.6 25.3 26.6 25.8 26.6 26.2C26.6 26.4 26.6 26.5 26.3 26.5C26.2 26.5 26 26.5 25.9 26.5C25.7 26.5 25.7 26.4 25.7 26.2C25.7 26 25.7 25.7 25.7 25.5V25.4C25.6 25.3 25.6 25.3 25.5 25.2C25.4 25.2 25.3 25.3 25.4 25.4C25.4 25.6 25.4 25.7 25.4 25.9C25.4 26.1 25.4 26.2 25.3 26.3C25.2 26.4 25.1 26.4 25 26.4C24.7 26.4 24.4 26.4 24 26.4C23.6 26.4 23.4 26.1 23.4 25.7C23.4 25.6 23.4 25.5 23.4 25.4C23.4 25.2 23.5 25.1 23.7 25C23.8 25 23.9 24.9 24 24.9C24.2 24.9 24.3 24.9 24.3 25.1C24.3 25.2 24.3 25.4 24.3 25.5C24.3 25.6 24.4 25.7 24.5 25.7C24.6 25.7 24.7 25.6 24.7 25.5C24.7 25.2 24.7 25 24.7 24.7C24.7 24.6 24.7 24.5 24.7 24.5C24.8 24.2 24.6 24.1 24.4 24.1C24.2 24.1 23.9 24.1 23.7 24.1C23.6 24.1 23.5 24 23.5 23.9C23.5 23.8 23.5 23.6 23.5 23.5C23.5 23.3 23.4 23.1 23.2 23.2H23.1C22.9 23.2 22.9 23.3 22.9 23.4C22.9 23.7 22.9 24 22.9 24.4C23 24.7 22.9 25 22.9 25.3C22.9 25.6 22.9 26 22.9 26.3C22.9 26.4 22.8 26.5 22.7 26.5C22.5 26.5 22.4 26.5 22.2 26.5C22.1 26.5 22.1 26.4 22.1 26.3C22.1 25.4 22.1 24.5 22.1 23.6C22.1 23.2 21.9 23.1 21.5 23.2C21.5 23.2 21.4 23.2 21.4 23.3C21.4 23.4 21.4 23.6 21.4 23.8C21.4 23.9 21.4 23.9 21.4 24C21.4 24.6 21.4 25.2 21.4 25.8C21.4 25.9 21.4 26 21.4 26.2C21.4 26.4 21.4 26.5 21.2 26.5C21 26.4 20.9 26.4 20.9 26.4ZM19.6 25.9C19.9 25.9 20.1 25.9 20.4 25.9L20.5 25.8C20.5 25.7 20.5 25.6 20.5 25.6C20.5 25.4 20.5 25.1 20.5 24.9C20.5 24.4 20.5 24 20.5 23.5C20.5 23.4 20.5 23.3 20.3 23.3C19.9 23.3 19.5 23.3 19.2 23.3C19.1 23.3 19 23.4 19 23.5C19 23.7 19.1 23.7 19.3 23.7C19.5 23.7 19.7 23.7 20 23.7C20.1 23.7 20.2 23.8 20.2 23.9C20.2 24.2 20.2 24.4 20.2 24.7C20.2 24.8 20.1 24.9 20.1 24.9C19.8 25.1 19.5 25.2 19.2 25.3C19 25.4 18.9 25.5 19 25.7C19 25.9 19.2 26 19.3 26C19.4 25.9 19.5 25.9 19.6 25.9ZM25 23.2C24.9 23.2 24.8 23.2 24.8 23.2C24.7 23.2 24.6 23.2 24.5 23.2C24.3 23.2 24.2 23.3 24.2 23.5C24.2 23.7 24.4 23.7 24.5 23.7C24.7 23.7 24.9 23.7 25.1 23.7C25.2 23.7 25.3 23.8 25.3 23.9C25.3 24.1 25.3 24.2 25.3 24.4C25.3 24.5 25.3 24.6 25.3 24.6C25.3 24.7 25.4 24.8 25.5 24.7C25.6 24.7 25.7 24.6 25.7 24.5C25.7 24.4 25.7 24.4 25.7 24.3C25.7 24 25.7 23.8 25.7 23.5C25.7 23.3 25.7 23.1 25.4 23.1C25.3 23.1 25.2 23.2 25 23.2Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M14.6 25.4C14.6 25.2 14.6 25 14.6 24.7C14.6 24.5 14.7 24.5 14.9 24.5C15 24.5 15.1 24.5 15.2 24.5C15.3 24.5 15.4 24.6 15.4 24.7C15.4 24.9 15.4 25.2 15.4 25.4C15.4 25.6 15.6 25.8 15.7 25.9H15.8C16.1 25.9 16.4 25.8 16.7 25.8C16.8 25.8 16.9 25.7 16.9 25.6C16.9 25.5 16.9 25.3 16.9 25.2C16.9 25 16.7 24.9 16.5 24.9C16.4 24.9 16.3 24.9 16.2 24.9C16.1 24.9 16 24.8 16 24.7C16 24.6 16 24.5 16 24.4C16 24.3 16.1 24.2 16.2 24.3C16.3 24.3 16.4 24.3 16.5 24.3C16.7 24.3 16.8 24.2 16.8 24C16.8 23.8 16.8 23.6 16.8 23.4C16.8 23.3 16.7 23.2 16.6 23.2C16.3 23.2 16 23.2 15.6 23.2C15.4 23.2 15.4 23.3 15.4 23.4C15.4 23.7 15.2 23.9 14.9 23.8C14.7 23.8 14.6 23.7 14.6 23.5C14.6 23.3 14.6 23 14.7 22.8C14.7 22.7 14.9 22.7 15 22.6C15.1 22.6 15.3 22.6 15.5 22.6C16.1 22.6 16.6 22.6 17.2 22.6C17.5 22.6 17.7 22.7 17.7 23C17.8 23.3 17.7 23.7 17.7 24C17.7 24.1 17.6 24.2 17.6 24.2C17.5 24.3 17.5 24.5 17.6 24.6C17.9 24.8 17.8 25.1 17.8 25.3C17.8 25.5 17.8 25.6 17.8 25.8C17.8 26.1 17.6 26.2 17.4 26.3C16.9 26.3 16.5 26.3 16 26.3C15.9 26.3 15.7 26.3 15.6 26.3C15.5 26.3 15.3 26.3 15.2 26.3C15.1 26.3 15 26.1 15 26C14.7 25.8 14.7 25.6 14.6 25.4C14.7 25.4 14.7 25.4 14.6 25.4Z" fill="black"/>
<path d="M20.1 27.4C20 27.4 19.8 27.4 19.7 27.4C19.6 27.4 19.5 27.4 19.4 27.3C19.4 27.2 19.4 27.1 19.4 27C19.4 27 19.5 26.9 19.6 26.9C19.8 26.9 20 26.9 20.2 26.9C20.3 26.9 20.4 26.9 20.5 27C20.5 27.1 20.5 27.3 20.5 27.4L20.4 27.5C20.3 27.4 20.2 27.4 20.1 27.4Z" fill="black"/>
<defs>
<linearGradient id="paint0_linear_46_5" x1="21.5" y1="36.6556" x2="21.5" y2="13.6425" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="white"/>
<stop offset="0.0612568" stop-color="#E9F8FD"/>
<stop offset="0.2564" stop-color="#A9E4F8"/>
<stop offset="0.4426" stop-color="#74D4F3"/>
<stop offset="0.615" stop-color="#4AC7F0"/>
<stop offset="0.7705" stop-color="#2DBEED"/>
<stop offset="0.9037" stop-color="#1AB8EC"/>
<stop offset="0.999" stop-color="#14B6EB"/>
</linearGradient>
</defs>
</svg>
```

I tried many things, but the SVG file should be correct. When in Flutter, I see the image in white.

Comment: Can you share flutter code, how do you use this svg?